# How to disable scrolling the document when sidr off-canvas menu is activated?

Tags: javascript

I use sidr off-canvas menu in my project (just my own project. I develop it just to learn more about website). I mean to make the content or the body tag be non-scroll as the off-canvas is activated but it doesn't work. I try to add property `'overflow:hidden;'`. But nothing work.

Could you please tell me how to dothat?

Comment: Can you add an example of the code you are working with. Thanks.

Comment: <script src="dist/jquery.sidr.js"></script>
       <script>

       window.onscroll = wind
        document.getElementById('off-canvas').onclick = function myfunction(){
            window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(0, 0); };
        }
    
       $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#off-canvas').sidr();
  
        });</script>